# Disable sql syntax highlighting in html code Goland IDE

Tags: go, settings, goland

I worked on my project, then, apparently, accidentally pressed hotkey. After that, the IDE highlights my html code like sql and tells me:

> No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance. Disable this inspection via problem menu

I do not use databases in the project. This syntax highlight annoys me

Please tell me how to disable it

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc6t7.png)

Comment: Open the file and go to File > Associate with File Type, and then select HTML.

Comment: Did not help. File already associated with HTML

Comment: Which IDE you are using ?

Comment: Can you check this website http://programmersought.com/article/86591293749/;jsessionid=725FDA6D067ACD83F0B8E15ED7326C6F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Settings/Preferences | Settings | Editor | File Types` and search for the `HTML` file type and make sure that the extension is associated in the `Registered patterns` section.

If the above doesn't work, then you'll have to take all the individual SQL formats available and search for your exact file name in them and remove that association when found.

Edit:

> No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance. Disable this inspection via problem menu

This refers to the fact that you have not connected the IDE to a supported database so it can assist you with the SQL related features. To learn more about that feature, use the [official help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/relational-databases.html).

Comment: Did not help. File already associated with HTM and I dont use any Database in project. I dont need connect to DB

Comment: Then open an issue on our tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and follow the steps to provide the IDE logs. Also, attach the `.idea` folder of the project.

Comment: Thanks, but my solution is - delete Goland config folder (../user/Golandxx/config) and restart IDE